# Android method invoke synchronously

Tags: android, methods

I'm getting installed application's size with this function:

```
Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);
getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, applicationInfo.packageName, new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
  @Override
  public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
    //my code here
  }
});
```

Since I have to display all informations in a `list`, how can I wait for this method to be completed before doing the same work for all my other applications?

Is there a way to call this `Method.invoke` synchronously?

## Edit

this is my full code:

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> applicationInfos;
    final PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
    applicationInfos = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    Context ctx = getContext();

    for (ApplicationInfo ai :
            applicationInfos) {
        if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
            allApps.add(new MyApp(pm, ai, ctx));
        }
    }
```

and this is the constructor (obv I can separate the size retrieving part and put it outside the constructor.

```
public MyApp(PackageManager pm, ApplicationInfo applicationInfo, Context ctx){

    MyApp.this.packageName = applicationInfo.packageName;
    MyApp.this.label = applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    MyApp.this.icon = applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);


    try {
        long installed = ctx
                .getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, 0)
                .firstInstallTime;

        MyApp.this.installDate = new Date(installed);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        MyApp.this.installDate = null;
    }

    try {
        Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);
        getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, applicationInfo.packageName,
                new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                            throws RemoteException {

                        int tempSize = Math.round((pStats.codeSize + pStats.cacheSize + pStats.dataSize) / 10000);
                        double finalSize = tempSize/100;
                        MyApp.this.size = finalSize;
                    }
                });

    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }

}
```

Comment: What about putting the subsequent code in the `//my code here` part?

Comment: @Denny thanks for replying! my problem is that this piece of code is inside a foreach loop, how can I stop the foreach iteration until the code is executed?

Comment: Could you add your loop to your example?

Comment: @Denny sure, done

Comment: Hmm... Can't really think of anything atm...

Comment: @Denny thanks anyway for your help!